# How can I control the value of a Field conditionally on redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to set the value of an input Field dynamically according the condition of other variable

I have this checkbox:

```
const roleWindowCheckbox = ({input, label}) => (
<Checkbox label={label}
        style={{width: '100%', display: 'inline-block'}}
        checked={input.value ? true : false}
        onCheck={input.onChange}
/>);
```

And I want to set the value of a component to 0 when the input is false

```
<Field
     format={(value) => numeral(value).format('$0,0.00')}
     normalize={(value) => {FormatTextUtil.formatCurrencyWithMaxDigit(value, 10)}}
     component={TextField}
     hintText='No Limit'
     name='refundVoidLimitField'
     disabled={!this.props.voidRefundEnabled}/>
```

`this.props.voidRefundEnabled` is a selector, so that's what I wish to use to change the input value, I tried to return the value on the normalize, but that didn't work, any ideas? The disable is working ok

Comment: It should be working with the normalize, what are you returning from FormatTextUtil.formatCurrencyWithMaxDigit(value, 10) ? You forget to mention what this function is doing internally

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was in the format of the field, the formatting was preventing me to see the result, but it was working correctly